# Gradle does not have execution permission

Tags: android, ios, windows, flutter, gradle

I am having this problem when I try to compile my first app in flutter. I have already read several solution proposals but they are for mac or linux, when I try to use the command: `chmod a + rx android / gradlew` it tells me it does not exist. I am using windows. I attach photos of the error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKzyu.png) [flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7k9A.png)

Comment: go to our project directory => android\app\build.gradle  change **compileSdkVersion 27 to compileSdkVersion 28**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot given the problem seems to be with where your project is located. Try moving your project into an accessible folder/ directory outside of the the C:/ or the current directory into something like C:/users/your_username/fluter_development/. This will make sure that gradle has the right permissions to download the necessary artifacts to build your app successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes caused by problems with internet connection or firewall blocks, check that your internet connection is okay and no firewall is blocking java.exe from accessing the internet